How to find the relative gap from an ojalgo optimisation result?
After the (mixed integer) model is successfully solved, how to find the relative gap of the result?
ExpressionsBasedModel model = new ExpressionsBasedModel();
//... create objective, variables and expressions ...
Optimisation.Result result = model.minimise();
if (result.getState().isFeasible()) {
    System.out.println("Objective Value = " + result.getValue());
    System.out.println("Relative Gap = ");
}


There is (currently) no way to extract that.
You control the MIP gap used in the solver by setting:
ConfigurableStrategy strategy = IntegerStrategy.DEFAULT.withGapTolerance(NumberContext.of(4));
model.options.integer(strategy);

By turning on progress logging the solver will output info regarding the solutions it finds:
model.options.progress(IntegerSolver.class); 

With the output from that progress logging you should be able to determine a suitable mip gap tolerance.
If the returned solution has state OPTIMAL then the gap is smaller than the configured tolerance.
NumberContext.of(4) is the lazy version of NumberContext.of(4,4) where the first digit is the precision (number of significant digits) and the second digit is the scale. Essentially the scale is used to determine if a number is zero or not, and the precision if two (non-zero) numbers are equal or not. Look at the code of NumberContext if you want the details on how it works. (You do not have exact control of the various thresholds used.)
You can set two different time limits:

model.options.time_abort is when to give up altogether
model.options.time_suffice is when a feasible, not necessarily optimal, solution is good enough

A suitable combination of time_suffice and GapTolerance can make a huge difference in practical use.
If you haven't already, I recommend reading this blog post about configuring MIP strategies:
https://www.ojalgo.org/2022/03/mip-strategy-configuration/
and I'd recommend reading the javadoc on Optimisation.Options:
https://javadoc.io/doc/org.ojalgo/ojalgo/latest/org/ojalgo/optimisation/Optimisation.Options.html

Is NumberContext.of(4) equivalent to a gap of 0.0001?  How would you set a target gap of 0.0005?  Is there a way to set a limit on run time too (i.e. the search will terminate whenever the gap or the time limit is reached)?

I updated the response to answer this.
